# Algoritmo SMS4 como trabajar con los bytes sobrantes?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo una aplicación que me cifra con el algoritmo SMS4 distintos archivos, este algoritmo funciona con bloques de 128 bits de entrada, mi programa va leyendo del archivo que quiero cifrar los datos en bloques de 128 bits es decir 16 bytes, realiza las transformaciones y lo envía a la salida, el problema radica en que necesito saber cuándo es el final del archivo para que la aplicación cifre la cantidad de datos exactos que son, el descriptor de final de archivo EOF y la función feof(); solo me sirven si lo que cifro es un txt, como alternativa utilice la función stat() que me dice la cantidad de Bytes que tiene mi archivo, entonces la condicion:

```
while(!feof(input)) {


 }
```

La sustituí por:

```
 struct stat archivo; 
/*estructura donde su miembro st_size guarda la cantidad de Bytes del archivo*/

   unsigned long cant_bytesleidos = 0;
   while(cant_bytesleidos < archivo.st_size){

   cant_bytesleidos +=16;//cantidad que leo para cifrar
    }
```

Haciendo esto el problema va a estar por ejemplo:
-El archivo tiene 65 bytes cada vez que leo cojo solo 16 bytes cuando haga este proceso 4 veces habré leído 64 bytes y me quedará uno por leer la condición todavía se va a cumplir cogiendo nuevamente del archivo 16 bytes más 1 será el que me faltaba los otros 15 serán basura o ceros;

Quisiera saber si esta es la forma de hacerlo o hay algún método o truco por ahí para realizar esto.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes, simplemente, leer X trozos de 16 bytes completos, y, en una última operación, leer los bytes restantes:

```
struct stat archivo;

unsigned long bloquesTotales = archivo.st_size / 16;
unsigned long bloquesLeidos = 0;
while( bloquesLeidos < bloquesTotales ){

    ++bloquesLeidos;
}

unsigned long resto = archivo.st_size % 16;
if( resto ) {
    // leemos los bytes restantes, SIEMPRE seran < 16.
}
```